# Getting a Method from a method reference

Tags: kotlin, reflection

I have a method inside a class:

```
class Foo {
    fun bar()
}
```

And I want to pass the method `bar` to a third-party library method that takes a `java.lang.reflect.Method` argument:

```
   fun baz(Method method)
```

How do I do that? Ideally is there some function call `f(Foo::bar)` that takes a method reference and returns a `Method`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With dependency `org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-reflect` you can write

```kotlin
import kotlin.reflect.jvm.javaMethod

val method = Foo::bar.javaMethod
```